# led and switchs program failure Tiva C board

Tags: arm, embedded, microcontroller

I'm trying to run this code on TIVA C board. `sw2` connected to `PF0`, `sw1` connected to `PF4` and RGB LED connected to `PF1`, `PF2` and `PF3`.

When I press `sw2` it shall turn the led blue and if `sw1` is pressed it shall turn the led green otherwise it shall be red.

The code doesn't function properly. I hope you can point out what I did wrong.

```
/*************************
PORT F Addresses
*************************/

#define RCGCGPIO (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x400FE608)) //CLOCK
#define PORTFDATA (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x400253FC)) //DATA
#define PORTFDIR (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x40025400)) //DIRECTION
#define PORTFDEN (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x4002551C)) //ENABLE
#define PORTFLOCK (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x40025520)) //LOCK (lock or       unlocks PF0)
#define PORTFCR (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x40025524)) //COMMIT (uncommit PF0)
#define PORTFPUR (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x40025510)) // PULL UP resistor
#define PORTFPDR (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x40025514)) // PULL Down resistor
/*************************/
int sw1;
int sw2;
int delay;
int main (void)
{
   RCGCGPIO = 0x20; //Enable clock for PORT F
   delay = RCGCGPIO;
   PORTFLOCK = 0x4C4F434B; // unlock commit reg
   PORTFCR   = 0x01; // unlock PF0
   PORTFDEN  = 0x1F; //Enable pins 0 to 4
   PORTFDIR  = 0x0E; // pins 0 and 4 input - pins 1,2,3 output
   PORTFPUR = 0x11;

   while (1)
   {
      sw2 = PORTFDATA & 0x00000001; 
      sw1 = PORTFDATA & 0x00000010;

      if (sw1 == 1)
         PORTFDATA |= 0x00000002;

      else if (sw2 == 1)
         PORTFDATA |= 0x00000004;

      else
         PORTFDATA |=  0x00000008;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two obvious problems with your code.  There are probably more...

You set `sw1 = PORTFDATA & 0x00000010`, so the only possible values `sw1` can have are 0x10 or 0x00.  Then you test `if (sw1 == 1)`.  But this test will never be true because `sw1` can never equal 1.

You use the `|=` operator to set the bits of `PORTFDATA`.  But nowhere do you ever clear the bits of `PORTFDATA`.  So your LEDs may turn on but they will never turn off.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the sample code comming with CCS to make sure that hardware are functional?

The sample code uses TI library instead of plain register Read & Write, however you can dig out the acutal register by `go to defination`. Anyway, I'm a bit curious about why you use plain register in the first place instead of TI library? ARM MCU is not 8051 anymore.

Comment: I have checked the board with other example programs and it is working fine. Regarding the Tivaware I have just found about it after I have written this code. Iam self studying embedded systems and still in the beginning.

Comment: AFAIK, you can get started by just using the library coming with CCS. Since you've already know that programming a MCU is nothing more than reading and writing register, it's time for you to write something more interesting using the library, rather than stuck with the register. (It's really hard for another person without a exactly same board to debug for you, I guess you may have just mistype a register adress or something in the above program...)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to keep in mind:
The launchpad buttons are negative logic, so if your switch1== 0x01, it is NOT being pressed.

Try something like:

```
If 
  sw1 == 0x01              //switch not pressed
    PORTFDATA &= ~(0x0E);    //ledz off
else
    PORTFDATA ^= 0x02;         //toggle red
```

I am also learning ARM & C solely self-study,  so I feel your pain. It took many hours of toggling single leds with bitwise operators just to fathom what is going on.   Stick with it!!!

/e